# Command line sort without -n flag

Tags: sorting, command-line

I'm trying to understand what happens if I use the `sort` command without the `-n` flag when the first character of each line of the file to be sorted is numeric. When I run

```
du /bin/* | sort
```

it looks like the output groups together all lines beginning with the same number and sorts within each of those groups, but the numbers are not sorted. So, here is a snippet of output that exemplifies this.

```
44  /bin/lsblk
44  /bin/ntfswipe
44  /bin/ping
44  /bin/ping6
44  /bin/rmdir
48  /bin/cat
48  /bin/ed
48  /bin/login
4   /bin/bzdiff
4   /bin/bzgrep
4   /bin/bzmore
4   /bin/gunzip
4   /bin/red
4   /bin/running-in-container
4   /bin/unicode_start
4   /bin/which
4   /bin/zcat
4   /bin/zcmp
4   /bin/zegrep
4   /bin/zfgrep
4   /bin/zforce
4   /bin/zless
4   /bin/zmore
```

Comment: This depends on the collation order, which depends on your locale. The easiest way to get a canonical answer would be to define your question to only apply with `LC_ALL=C` in the environment.

Comment: I would recommend `LC_COLLATE=C` instead, so that it doesn't mess up the terminal's character encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-numeric sort is a sort character-by-character in locale-specified order. The easiest locale to describe this for is `C`, which does a sort by ASCII order; if you're in a different locale, spaces may sort either before or after numbers, depending on how its collation order is defined. (Only a very weird locale would not sort characters `0` through `9` in their conventional order, but a locale could in fact be defined to do just that!).

For the `C` locale, though -- a space character has the ASCII value of 32, whereas the numbers 0 through 9 have ASCII values 48 through 57. Thus, `5<Space>` sorts after `49`, but before `60`.

If this doesn't make sense, replace the characters with other things whose collation order is more natural to you. For instance, let's call a space `A`, and `0` through `9` as `B` through `K`. Then, `49` becomes `DK`, `5<Space>` becomes `EA`, and `60` becomes `GB`. It should be normal to expect `DK` to be before `EA`, which is in turn before `GB`.